# Как получить строку из SOAP запроса

Tags: xml, kotlin, soap, retrofit2, okhttp

Собственно в чем проблема, я сделал POST запрос на веб-сервис [Веб сервис](https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?op=NumberToWords) и получил ответ

Запрос

```html
--> POST https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 247
Accept-Charset: utf-8
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <NumberToWords xmlns="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
         <ubiNum>1000</ubiNum>
      </NumberToWords>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
--> END POST (247-byte body)
```

Ответ

```html
<-- 200 https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso (1333ms)
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: Server
web-service: DataFlex 19.1
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
date: Thu, 02 Nov 2023 15:52:53 GMT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:NumberToWordsResponse xmlns:m="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
      <m:NumberToWordsResult>one thousand</m:NumberToWordsResult>
    </m:NumberToWordsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
<-- END HTTP (344-byte body)
```

из этого ответа я бы хотел достать "one thousand" Как мне это сделать?

код интерфейс

```html
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.POST


interface soapAPI {

    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
    )
    @POST("webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso")
    suspend fun sendApi(@Body envelope: SoapEnvelope): Response<output>
}
```

Код запроса

```html
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Namespace(prefix = "soap", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@Root(name = "Envelope")
data class SoapEnvelope(
    @field:Element(name = "soap:Body", required = false)
    var body: SoapBody? = null
)

@Root(name = "soap:Body", strict = false)
data class SoapBody(
    @field:Element(name = "NumberToWords")
    var numberToWords: NumberToWords? = null
)

@Root(name = "NumberToWords", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
data class NumberToWords(
    @field:Element(name = "ubiNum", required = false)
    var ubiNum: String? = null
)
```

Дата класс для получения ответа(наверное тут и есть слабое место моего кода)

```html
data class output(
    val ubiNum: String
)
```

retrofit2, okHttp3, simpleXML

```html
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.dataaccess.com/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val productApi = retrofit.create(soapAPI::class.java)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val envelope = SoapEnvelope(
                body = SoapBody(
                    numberToWords = NumberToWords("1000")
                )
            )
            Log.d("check", "перед ошибкой")
            val response = productApi.sendApi(envelope)
            Log.d("check", "после ошибки") //это не выполняется
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val output = response.body()
                Log.d("check", "${output}") 
            }
            else {
                val errorBody = response.errorBody()
                Log.d("check", "ошибка")// выполняется если неправильный запрос
            }
        }
```

При код 200 вылетает фатальная ошибка, приложение крашится

```html
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10024
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Body' does not have a match in class com.example.myapplication.output at line -1
    at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:45)
    at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@a4ec63, Dispatchers.IO]
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Body' does not have a match in class com.example.myapplication.output at line -1
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:527)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Injector.read(Composite.java:1433)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
    at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
```

Не судите строго, занимаюсь подобным первый раз и много чего еще не понимаю, также хочу попросить совета где набрать информации по данной теме, спасибо.

Comment: Вы же расписали так красиво `SoapEnvelope` для запроса, так же и ответ распишите. А то бац, и `Response<output>` какой-то, да и еще с маленькой буквы :)

Comment: То есть мне надо сделать data class soapResponse, в который надо загнать уже xml response и вместо Response<output> написать Response<soapResponse>. Правильно понимаю?

Comment: у вас есть готовое описание [soap сервиса](https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?WSDL) осталось только по wsdl сгенерировать классы и вызывать нужный метод

Comment: @Arsusen, что-то типа такого. Только с большой буквы все классы и интефейсы, так принято. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался, как это работает, собственно вот

Интерфейс

```html
interface soapAPI {

    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
    )
    @POST("webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso")
    suspend fun sendApi(@Body envelope: SoapEnvelope): Response<SoapResponse>
}
```

код запроса

```html
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Namespace(prefix = "soap", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@Root(name = "Envelope")
data class SoapEnvelope(
    @field:Element(name = "soap:Body", required = false)
//    @field:Path("soap:Body")
    var body: SoapBody? = null
)

@Root(name = "soap:Body", strict = false)
data class SoapBody(
    @field:Element(name = "NumberToWords")
    var numberToWords: NumberToWords? = null
)

@Root(name = "NumberToWords", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
data class NumberToWords(
    @field:Element(name = "ubiNum", required = false)
    var ubiNum: String? = null
)
```

код ответа

```html
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root

@Root(name = "Envelope", strict = false)
data class SoapResponse(
    @field:Element(name = "Body", required = false)
    var body: GetResult? = null
)

@Root(name = "Body", strict = false)
data class GetResult(
    @field:Element(name = "NumberToWordsResponse", required = false)
    var response: GetResponse? = null
)

@Root(name = "NumberToWordsResponse",strict = false)
data class GetResponse(
    @field:Element(name = "NumberToWordsResult", required = false)
    var text: String? = null
)
```

Очень много время потратил на то, что в коде ответа не нужны были префиксы, часто получал null вместо нормального ответа.